# asp:ListView SelectedIndexChanging not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, events

I've searched in google and bing and seen all posts and even in stackoverflows search but couldn't find the solution.

To be sure about the error I've created a new project it has 1 page which has:

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ListView" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListView_OnSelectedIndexChanged" OnSelectedIndexChanging="ListView_OnSelectedIndexChanging">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label" Text='<%#Eval("UserName") %>' ></asp:Label><br/>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource" SelectCommand="Select * FROM Users" ConnectionString="<%$ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Output:

[image]

Because I've 2 users with name A and B.

**Now the problem is that events OnSelectedIndexChanged and OnSelectedIndexChanging are not firing when I click on A or B.** How to get the selected index where user is clicking?

Complete Project if anyone wants to look, actually there is no need to: https://app.box.com/s/bhs682q6fqai784kao0zv1tcxgxecr4s

Comment: Kindly share `OnSelectedIndexChanged` and `OnSelectedIndexChanging` written in code-behind.

Comment: It's empty with a breakpoint. Debugger isn't entering it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ListView.SelectedIndexChanging Event occurs when an item's **Select button is clicked**, but before the ListView control handles the select operation.
 (A Select button is a button control whose CommandName property is set to "Select".)

Change your code to

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ListView" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListView_OnSelectedIndexChanged" OnSelectedIndexChanging="ListView_OnSelectedIndexChanging" AutoPostBack="true">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label" Text='<%#Eval("UserName") %>' ></asp:Label>
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="ButtonSelect" CommandName="Select" Text="SelectButton"/><br/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```